# Consulta Laravel Eloquent 3 tabelas belongtomany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unTQB.png)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnfw0.png)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXYoD.png)

Tenho 3 tabelas, `Users`, `Roles` e `Permissions`

***Exemplo:***

`User` Carlos tem 1 `Role` `Admin` e 1 `Role` `Admin` tem 2 `Permissions` `admin` e `user`

```
count(Auth::user()
       ->roles()
       ->with('permissions')
       ->whereHas('permissions', function ($q) {
           $q->where('name', 'superadmin');
       })
       ->get()) > 0
```

aqui da certo a consulta mas, se for listar todos eu queria ocultar só quem tiver a `permission` `admin`

```
$user = new User();
$users = $user
      ->roles()
      ->with('permissions')
      ->whereDoesntHave('permissions', function ($q) {
          $q->where('name', 'admin');
      })
      ->get();
```

Comment: Alguma reposta resolveu seu problema? se não pode adicionar na sua perguntas as entidades que componha essa filtro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa sua dúvida já tive um dia acho que é exatamente isso aqui que você quer:

```
$user = User::with('roles', 'roles.permissions')->where('id', auth()->user->id)->first();

dd($user->roles); // retorno de todas as roles
dd($user->roles->permissions); // retorno de todas permissions
```

Answer (score 0):

Da forma que você fez traz o resultado desejado, e por fim você não quer o que possua nome admin inclua na query um segundo parâmetro, por padrão quando o segundo parâmetro é omitido o Eloquent entende que vc faz a comparação por igualdade

```
$user = new User();
$users = $user
      ->roles()
      ->with('permissions')
      ->whereDoesntHave('permissions', function ($q) {
          $q->where('name','!=' ,'admin');
      })
      ->get();
```